# vCalendar - show as (Free/Busy/Tentative/Out of Office)

Tags: outlook, calendar, vcalendar

I sent a vCalendar message to Outlook which results in a new Event in Outlook Calendar.
How to set "Show As" field? (Free/Busy/Tentative/Out of Office)

Comment: did any of the below work for you? Would be good to accept an answer :)

Answer (score 5):

I saw this line in the .ics file created by Outlook 2010

```
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:FREE
```

so it looks like Microsoft has "extended" the vcal spec to suit their purposes.  I can confirm that adding that line does work when a feed is viewed in Outlook and seems to cause no harm when consumed by the iPhone's calendar app.

Answer (score 5):

```
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:OOF
```

Marks the 'out of office' calendar for  outlook

[source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-oxcical/cd68eae7-ed65-4dd3-8ea7-ad585c76c736)

Answer (score 4):

It turns out that in the standard there's a place for this, missed by Sean:

> 4.2.9 Free/Busy Time Type
>
> Parameter Name: FBTYPE
>
> Purpose: To specify the free or
>   busy time type.
>
> Format Definition: The property
>   parameter is defined by the following 
>   notation:
>
> ```
>  fbtypeparam        = "FBTYPE" "=" ("FREE" / "BUSY"
>                     / "BUSY-UNAVAILABLE" / "BUSY-TENTATIVE"
>                     / x-name
>     ; Some experimental iCalendar data type.
>                     / iana-token)
>
>
>
>     ; Some other IANA registered iCalendar data type.
> ```
>
> Description: The parameter
>   specifies the free or busy time type.
>   The    value FREE indicates that the
>   time interval is free for scheduling. 
>   The value BUSY indicates that the time
>   interval is busy because one    or
>   more events have been scheduled for
>   that interval. The value
>   BUSY-UNAVAILABLE indicates that the
>   time interval is busy and that    the
>   interval can not be scheduled. The
>   value BUSY-TENTATIVE indicates    that
>   the time interval is busy because one
>   or more events have been
>   tentatively scheduled for that
>   interval. If not specified on a
>   property that allows this parameter,
>   the default is BUSY.
>
> Example: The following is an
>   example of this parameter on a
>   FREEBUSY    property.
>
> ```
>  FREEBUSY;FBTYPE=BUSY:19980415T133000Z/19980415T170000Z
> ```

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't seem to work.  Perhaps my implementation but I think FREEBUSY is for the VFREEBUSY component, not VEVENT.

Answer (score 2):

Which status field do you mean? Do you mean when replying to a meeting request or when sending information about a meeting?

Either way, the answer is in the vCalendar standard document. I think you mean the STATUS field. Wikipedia has an example of this field as:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:1.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
CATEGORIES:MEETING
STATUS:TENTATIVE
DTSTART:19960401T033000Z
DTEND:19960401T043000Z
SUMMARY:Your Proposal Review
DESCRIPTION:Steve and John to review newest proposal material
CLASS:PRIVATE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCalendar#vCalendar_1.0

The standards document for the format is: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2445.txt

You might also try creating an event in outlook, saving it as a vCard, and then opening the vCard in notepad. This will show you how outlook saves the information.

The documentation leads me to believe that you can only set a Busy or Tentative status:

> 4.8.1.11 Status
>
> Property Name: STATUS
>
> Purpose: This property defines the
>   overall status or confirmation for
>   the calendar component.
>
> Value Type: TEXT
>
> Property Parameters: Non-standard
>   property parameters can be
>   specified on this property.
>
> Conformance: This property can be
>   specified in "VEVENT", "VTODO" or
>   "VJOURNAL" calendar components.
>
> Description: In a group scheduled
>   calendar component, the property is
>   used by the "Organizer" to provide a
>   confirmation of the event to the
>   "Attendees". For example in a "VEVENT"
>   calendar component, the    "Organizer"
>   can indicate that a meeting is
>   tentative, confirmed or    cancelled.
>   In a "VTODO" calendar component, the
>   "Organizer" can    indicate that an
>   action item needs action, is
>   completed, is in    process or being
>   worked on, or has been cancelled. In a
>   "VJOURNAL"    calendar component, the
>   "Organizer" can indicate that a
>   journal entry    is draft, final or
>   has been cancelled or removed.
>
> Format Definition: The property is
>   defined by the following notation:
>
> ```
>  status     = "STATUS" statparam] ":" statvalue CRLF
>
>  statparam  = *(";" xparam)
>
>  statvalue  = "TENTATIVE"           ;Indicates event is
>                                     ;tentative.
>             / "CONFIRMED"           ;Indicates event is
>                                     ;definite.
>             / "CANCELLED"           ;Indicates event was
>                                     ;cancelled.
>     ;Status values for a "VEVENT"
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Since RFC 2445 and 5545 both do not support the statuses OOO and Tentative, you can use the property X-MICROSOFT-CDO-INTENDEDSTATUS: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee203636(v=exchg.80).aspx

Comment: Tentative is in RFC 5545, see https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5545#section-3.2.9. (Whether it is supported by CalDAV clients is another issue.) I don't think ‘AWAY’ maps to OOO.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if things have changed over the years, but I was able to use this to automatically set things to be Tentative:

```
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:TENTATIVE
```

Answer (score 0):

I use python to import win32,
for this is one attribute called BUSYSTATUS,
the value can define the status of shows
FREE=0,1=TENTIVE,2=BUSY

```
import win32com.client as win32


outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
myItem = outlook.CreateItem(1)
myItem.MeetingStatus =(1) ## this means it is an appointment
myItem.BUSYSTATUS=0 ## SHOW AS 0=FREE,1=TENTIVE,2=BUSY
```